# Underline height in Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Did someone know how to change the size of underline in NSAttributedString ?

I tried `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleThick` and `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle`, but both are too 'bold'

Thanks

Comment: No current way all built in. But you could always play with CoreText, but that's a lot more complex.

Comment: If I had to do this on my own, i'll use CoreGraphics instead. But thanks for answer